# Visual Studio 2010 is showing Intellisense for ASP.NET MVC 2.0 in a Project that uses ASP.NET MVC 1.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

i am having a rather strange issue with Visual Studio 2010, the Intellisense for HtmlHelper is showing me the methodes of ASP.NET MVC 2.0 but the project only has a reference to ASP.NET MVC 1.0 (specific version is set to true).

this is only happening in the views, when i am using the HtmlHelper in a custom extension method the intellisense is correct.

the project itself compiles without errors and run`s with ASP.NET MVC 1.0

Comment: its probably encouraging you to upgrade :)

Comment: Then this is obviously a bug: The latest version is ASP.NET MVC 3. ;-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i found a solution, but it`s only a solution as long as you dont have any ASP.NET MVC 2.0 sites.

you need to uninstall ASP.NET MVC 2.0 - Tools for Visual Studio 2010 and ASP.NET MVC 2.0. if your project does not open after this, you need to edit your project file and change

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

to

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

now you`ve got Intellisense for ASP.NET MVC 1.0 under VS 2010